# Zeroclipboard with php and multiple elements

Tags: php, copy, clipboard, zeroclipboard

So I have multiple elements on a webpage which I am wanting to be able to be copied. 
The elements are outputted with php depending on what an API sends back. I have been trying for 2 days to get this to work but I cant seem to see what's wrong with my code.

This is the code with all the unimportant things taken out

```
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sweetalert.css">
<script type="text/javascript">

var clipboard = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById("copy"));

clipboard.on("ready", function(readyEvent) {
    clipboard.on("aftercopy", function(event) {
      sweetalert({
          title: "See you soon!",
          text: "Copied " + event.data["text/plain"],
          type: "success",
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 2000
      });
    });
});
</script>

  <?php
    echo "<button class='btn btn-success' id='copy' data-clipboard-text='". $element ."'><i class='fa fa-copy'> </i> Copy</button>";
  ?>
```

Comment: Zero clipboard still is the only more or less reliable way to do that. The new html5 clicpboard api is still not implemented reliably enough to use it. Note however that zero clipboard requires flash to be installed in the client browser, which is getting less and less frequent. Also it uses a security gap which might be closed on day...

Comment: So is the flash movie placed over the button? You can check with right clicking on the button. Also you should check your browsers development console for any javascript errors.

Comment: Oh, and another thing I just see: you apparently do not `htmlescape()` that `$element` value you inject in your button definition. That might break your markup, depending on the content.

Comment: How do you place the flash movie over the button?

Comment: It is (should be) done by the zeroclipboard button when initializing the elements. If not, then why doesn't it work? Maybe no flash installed in your browser? Also give it a try to dump the `clipboard` variable into your javascript console to see if the initialization works.

Comment: @arkascha it says (anonymous function) for the script


    var clipboard = new      ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById("copy"));
    
    clipboard.on("ready", function(readyEvent) {
        clipboard.on("aftercopy", function(event) {
          sweetalert({
              title: "See you soon!",
              text: "Copied " + event.data["text/plain"],
              type: "success",
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 2000
          });
        });
    });

Comment: Looks fine. So back to the movie...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PHP, go with javascript like this :

```
function ClipBoard(id) {
    youobj = document.getElementById(id);
    holdtext.innerText = youobj.innerText;
    therange = holdtext.createTextRange();
    therange.execCommand("RemoveFormat"); 
    therange.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I was able to make a fix for this! It was much easier than I thought. I used a class for each element which I wanted to be copied but I still used the same ID's for each & included the data-clipboard-text tag. So the final code looks like this

```
//This Will load the lib
<script src="js/zeroclipboard.js"></script>
//This is the script. I should probably but it in its own .js file.
<script>
//Loading it with the document ready function meant that I wont have any
//Errors to do with the initialization of it.
  $(document).ready(function() {
//This makes a new var called clipboard and it will look for the class called "copyclass".
//If you try to find elements via ID it will not be able to because you can only
//use ID's with the same name once.
    var clipboard = new ZeroClipboard($('.copyclass'));

      clipboard.on("ready", function(readyEvent) {
        clipboard.on("aftercopy", function(event) {
//Simple JS alert.
          alert("Worked!");
        });
      });
    });
</script>

<?php
//The data which is sent to be used for the clipboard is then dyncamically assigned using
//PHP for the data-clipboard-text.
echo  "<td><button class='copyclass' id='copy' data-clipboard-text='". $element ."'><i class='fa fa-copy'> </i> Copy</button> </td>";
?>
```